# how to work with postgres database using coroutines

Tags: python-asyncio, psycopg2, aiopg

We're building a backend service utilizing asyncio framework (in our case aiohttp).

We're using aiopg to make queries to the database.

Since this is one-threaded server, what is the correct implementation pattern of making a database query:

1) The server should keep just one connection, and each coroutine should simply `aquire()` a new cursor on that connection object?

or

2) The server should open a new connection for each coroutine?

Question about scenario (1): does it guarantee concurrency? Can the database run multiple async queries `await cursor.execute()` on one connection? I am pretty sure that in the non-async mode, cursors on the same connections are simply serialized. Is this different when using async? If yes, what is a max limit of cursors that can be acquired simultaneously?

Question about scenario (2): is this a valid scenario for a one-threaded asyncio server at all?

Comment: Without knowing more about your application's architecture it's a bit hard to give specific help, but you probably want to use a connection pool. The [aiopg docs](https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#basics) include an example of using a pool.

Comment: I am using conn pool. The question is rather simple: when having multiple concurrent users (multiple coroutines making queries to the DB simultaneously) should each coroutine open a new connection or just new cursor from shared connection?

Comment: If you are using a pool, all of your connections are already shared, so getting a new one or reusing an old one are effectively the same thing.